# Which headers are platform independent?

Tags: c, header, platform-independent

I want to write a software which should compile on different platforms. Say MS and Unix. Which headers can I use without thinking about platform dependency?

I *guess* I can use

- stdlib.h
- stdio.h
- stdint.h
- stdarg.h
- inttypes.h
- string.h
- time.h
- limits.h
- math.h
- float.h
- errno.h

Please tell me if I'm wrong and please tell me more headers. I tried google, but it does not give me the answers I'm looking for.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header - that lists C _standard_ headers.